# Scaling y-axis of a histogram

Tags: image-processing, histogram

I am creating a histogram of an image. I need a way to scale it in y-axis to represent it nicely, as standard image/video processing programs do. Thus I need to make stronger the small values, to make weaker the big values. 
What I tried to do so far:
To scale the y-values by dividing them by the greatest y value. It allowed me to see it, but still small values are almost indistinguishable from zero.

What I have seen: 
In a standard video processing tool let's say three biggest values have the same y-values on their histogram representation. However, real values are different. And the small values are amplified on the histogram.

I would be thankful for the tips/formula/algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can create lookup table (LUT), fill it with values from a curve that describes desired behavior. Seems that you want something like [gamma curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction)

```
for i in MaxValue range
      LUT[i] = MaxValue(255?) * Power(i/MaxValue, gamma)
```

To apply it:

```
for every pixel
    NewValue = LUT[OldValue]
```

Comment: Thank you. The gamma power brings better view of the graph. And I still didn't get the trick about having the highest peak on the same level that image processing programs use

Comment: Do you want contrast stretching? Your "y-axis scale" for histogram is not clear for me yet